# Winston log format

Tags: json, node.js, winston

i am using Winston ^3.0.0-rc6 as below :

```
var options = {
    file: {
        level: 'info',
        filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        prettyPrint: true,
        maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: true,

    }
};

const jsonFormatter = (logEntry) => {
    if (logEntry.type) {
        const base = {
            timestamp: new Date()
        };
        const json = Object.assign(base, logEntry);
        logEntry[MESSAGE] = JSON.stringify(json);
    } else {
        logEntry = "";
    }

    return logEntry;
}

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format(jsonFormatter)(),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.file)
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.uncaughtExceptions)
    ]
});
```

my log output :

```
{"timestamp":"2018-06-10T07:41:03.387Z","type":"Authentication","status":"failed","level":"error","message":"Incorrect password"}
```

but i want them to be like :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-06-10T07:41:03.387Z",
    "type": "Authentication",
    "status": "failed",
    "level": "error",
    "message": "Incorrect password"
}
```

i tried to play around with json : true , and prettyPrint but it did not do the trick .

Can any one help please

Thanks.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried `JSON.stringify(json, 0, 2)`?

Comment: @marcusstenbeck works !! thank you so much

Comment: @marcusstenbeck please add it as answer so i can mark it solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed in your code that on the line

```
logEntry[MESSAGE] = JSON.stringify(json);
```

you're using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which takes two more optional arguments

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
```

If you set `space` to the amount of spaces you'd like you'll get the output you're looking for. So change the initial line to be:

```
logEntry[MESSAGE] = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);  // or 4 ;)
```

*(The `replacer` argument is `null` because we don't want to change the default behavior.)*

Answer (score 0):

This is deprecated: You can check the link [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#transports).

> I tried to play around with json: true, and prettyPrint but it did not do the trick.

Simple code like this work for you:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [
    //
    // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
    // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
    //
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
  ]
});
```

If this does not work, let me know so that I can improvise.

Comment: nope that did not work , it keep printing in one line not like the format i provide , 

thanks

Comment: @AhmadKhalaf It's completely undocumented, but I found that `winston.format.json()` takes an object as its parameter, with the format: `{ replacer?: (key: string, value: any) => any, space?: string | number }` corresponding to the params of the `JSON.stringify()` method. So simply call it like `winston.format.json({ replacer: null, value: 3 })` to match the behaviour of `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 3)`.